# Giving <td>-Elements an ID with JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, html-table

I'am new to Javascript/Jquery and JSP.
I have a `<table>` created with JSP ( 2 for-loops ), and with Javascript I can click on every Cell.This opens a new Window (Window is opened by Bootstrap Script) with an Text Input and an DELETE and SAVE-BUTTON.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
        <%for(int i = 0; i <bsp.length;i++) { %>
            <%if(i==0){ %>
                <th></th>
            <%} %>
            <th><%out.println(bsp[i]); %></th>
        <%} %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%for(int ut = 0; u < test.length ;u++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%out.println(test[u]); %></td>
                <%for(int rest =0; rest<bsp.length;rest++) { %>
                <td id="ID00" class="td_test"></td>
                <%} %>
            </tr>
        <%} %>
    </tbody>
```

`$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#save").click(function() {
                    $(".td_test").append($("#input").val());
                });
            });`

The Problem is, that every `<td>`-Element has the same Class, and if I change one Cell, it changes the whole Table.If i use ID-Selektor, it only works with the very first Cell in Table.

Anyone has some ideas how I can solve that individually?

Comment: ID in HTML should be always unique. So use `id="ID<% = rest + 1 %>"`

Comment: append numbers i.e. rest to your td_test and access by .td_test_1 and so on..

Comment: How do you open up the dialog (*"new window"*?) That should save a reference to its originator somewhere

Comment: The new Window is opened like this : $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".td_test").click(function() {
    $("#bModal").modal('show');
   });
  });

Comment: @lolio Inside that click handler, `this` will reference the originating `td`, grab it there. Also, is that `.modal()` the bootstrap widget? If yes, you really should edit that info into the question

Comment: yes its the Bootstrap Modal, sry  , i will edit this.So i can just use $(this) instead of all my ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, grab the originating element inside its click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentlyOpenedTd; // name it something more sensible
    $(".td_test").click(function() {
         $("#bModal").modal('show');
         currentlyOpenedTd = this;
    });
    $("#save").click(function() {
         $(currentlyOpenedTd).text($("#input").val());
    });
});
```

An aside: also notice that I changed `.append` to `.text`, even though they're not exactly the same. Modify to suit your requirements, but keep in mind it's good practice to always sanitize user input.

Answer (score 0):

-<%rest%>">
Then u will get different class names for each td and can bind events easily